# Command failed due to signal Segmentation fault 11

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

just switched over to Swift2, and am getting this compiler error. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
nameSpotQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)

        }

        if let objects = results as? [PFObject]{
            self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for object in objects {
                let name = object.objectForKey("Name") as! String
                self.searchResults.append(name)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                self.searchBars.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try removing `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){`

Comment: Removed dispatch didn't work :(

Comment: collectionTestViewController.swift:68:47 - line:94:9] it's on a line that just has a bracket...

Comment: since the update today, I get the same error when calling the function `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, you will probably find, that even if you comment out everything inside, it won't compile

Answer (score 0):

Change `[AnyObject]?` for `[PFObject]?` in the block.

This was updated on ParseSDK 1.8.3, download the latest version if you haven't.

Hope I could help.